# What can I do to improve my listening comprehension for JLPT N3?

Tags: discussion

I'm studying for the JLPT N3 of December 2019.Everyday I learn 30 new words through flashcards and review past flashcards using anki, and when I read I don't have much trouble understanding the meaning of the text. What I struggle the most in is Listening Comprehension; most of the time, I do have already studied the words they are saying, but i don't identify them in the moment. Can someone advice me on how to solve this problem?
手伝っていただけませんか？

Comment: Also, you say at first that when you read you have no problem, but after that you say that you struggle the most in Reading Comprehension. Did you mean _Listening_ Comprehension, maybe?

Comment: Yes, thank you. sorry

Comment: are you using audio learning tools as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a textbook, try to dump the audio exercises (most textbooks have some kind of audio exercises, or at least audio recordings of certain texts in each lesson) into your laptop and play them with a software that lets you adjust the playing speed (I use [VLC player](https://www.videolan.org)). Then, you can play the audio files at a slow pace for you at first, and increase it little by little until you are comfortable with a faster speed.

Another idea, you could try to make *audio* anki flashcards, where you record sentences (rather than isolated words) read at a natural speed with those words that are difficult for you.

As for the materials, aside from the textbook audios, there are other resources ([日本語総まとめ聴解](https://omgjapan.com/products/nihongo-so-matome-jlpt-n3-listening-comprehension), [完全マスター聴解](https://www.3anet.co.jp/np/resrcs/364420/), etc.) specifically designed to improve your listening skills for the test, but I haven't tried them.

Answer (score 1):

2 things: Podcasts and [Satori Reader](https://www.satorireader.com/articles). In addition, NHK easy news (https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/index.html) although it may be too easy for N3.

I have a look into the podcast channel JLPT stories by JLPT stories team and it is really good:

Pros:

1. It tailors for each JLPT levels. The stories all intentionally cover some JLPT level grammars, for example 必ずしも ... とは限らない for N3.
2. It provides the transcript, you can read and repeat the parts.
3. Free

Con:

Stories are increasing, but currently only 20 stories

Satori Reader

This is actually a spin-off of Human Japanese app (really good intro into Japanese), from the same team and same methodology:

Pro:

1. Transcript is interactively presented so you can pop up windows for each word for translation and grammar explanation.
2. Large amount of articles, covering many diverse topics: news, stories and dialogues. All annotated as described above.
3. Each individual sentence has its own segment audio, no need to scroll to repeat it.

Con:

It costs money (it supports the developer to provide more such content, not exactly a con)